RPi 5 : HDMI "No signal" or "No compatible signal"
I got a brand new RPi 5. Without SD card, I can see the boot screen, waiting for a SD card to be inserted.
But when the SD card is inserted, I only get a black screen: my monitor displays a "No Signal" or "No compatible resolution" depending on the trials.
I have tried several config options from the comments and answers on this thread.
I tried the config from this video.
All to no avail.
Any idea?

when the SD card is inserted what is on the SD card? Have you tried a USB thumb drive instead?

Did the diagnostic screen say EDID none? What resolution screen? Try a different screen?

The brand new 64GB SD card is just loaded with Raspberry Pi OS 64bits installed from the Raspberry Pi Imager v1.8.4. I've tried two HD displays (1920x1080). Same results. The screen without the SD card says : display: DISP0: HPD=0 EDID:none #0 DISP1: DVI HPD=1 EDID:none #0.

You can edit the config.txt file and adjust the HDMI Settings.

Try editing cmdline.txt and forcing your resolution: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=363503#p2180453

I already modified /bootfs/config.txt and /bootfs/cmdline.txt and nothing changed. /rootfs/boot/firmware is empty. Shall I copy /bootfs/config.txt and /bootfs/cmdline.txt to /rootfs/boot/firmware and modify them there?
